# How do you edit the Info.Plist file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to create a document-based application but the problem is that I don't know how to edit the Info.plist file in order to let the application open certain types of files.  I've looked through the apple's "Document-Based Applications Overview" guide to help, but to no avail.

I want my application to open .txt files and .rtf files.  My interface only has a simple text view.

Please help.  Thanks

Edit:

Every time I compile my code, my app just loads, but it shows an alert panel saying "No Document could be created".  And in the log it just says "The public.rtf type doesn't map to any NSDocumentClass."

As for my properties tab, I have "Text Document" for my CFBundleTypeName and "public.rtf" for my LSItemContentTypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Document-Based Applications Overview has a section called [Storing Document Types Information in the Application's Property List](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Documents/Concepts/DocTypePList.html). In that section, they explain how to edit Info.plist so that it lists supported document types. Their example is TextEdit, which opens RTF and plain text files much like what you want.

To open the window depicted in Figure 1, double click your target in the project folder tree (under the Targets section) and select the Properties tab.

Comment: Before I edited the properties tab, it still worked (except for the saving and opening files part), but after I edited the properties tab, whenever I try to compile the app, it shows an alert panel saying that "No document could be created".  It's been driving me crazy!

Comment: @theAmateurProgrammer can you edit your original question and post all error messages you get, the alert panel (as an image), the properties tab (as an image), and the relevant contents of your Info.plist file?

Comment: @theAmateurProgrammer Did you specify `NSDocumentClass` as the document class in your Info.plist file? Have you created a class called `NSDocumentClass`?

Comment: Yes, I do have the NSDocumentClass Key.

Comment: Never mind.  I forgot to rename the file name in the class declaration.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

simply click it in xcode.
you also have the option to show it in source code style (xml-like).
for that right.click in xcode the plist file -> "open as" -> "source code file" (or something like that".

Comment: That's not what I meant, I meant as in the document type in order to open certain file types.

Answer (score 1):

in info.plist 
in CFBundleDocumentTypes Key add CFBundleTypeName and set its values as extension for example to add support for word file add DOC as its value

There is [nice article](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/06/14/ipad-sdk-3-2-document-support-1/) about it